# Integration of upper half of unit circle with fubini's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, circles, fubini-tonelli-theorems

So I have to calculate the integration of the upper half of the unit circle $K$ with Fubini´s theorem, where

$$K = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid (x^2 + y^2 \leq 1)\wedge(y\geq 0)\}$$

The given function is $f(x,y) = x^{2}y$.

I am thinking, is it possible that i use the parametrization coordinate, i.e $x = r\cos(t)$, $y = r\sin(t)$, and $r$ from $0$ to $1$, $t$ from $0$ to $\pi$ to calculate the integration function?

Would be glad if someone could help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Of course, you can.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The integral you are interested in is given by
\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}rf(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help! I did it exactly this way except that i exchanged the position of dr and dθ as well as the integral! But the result should be the same.